# Каким образом линкер решает проблему с ODR для шаблонов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, линковка

Каким образом линкер решает проблему с ODR для шаблонов? Ведь в каждом translation unit у нас должна быть инстанциация шаблона (т.е. в каждом объектном файле, который линкер должен собрать).

Comment: ЕМНИП, берет реализацию из любого объектного файла на свой выбор. Поэтому если реализации вдруг оказались разные, то программа - ill formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Шаблон это заготовка типа. Инстанциированный шаблон это тип. Объявлений типа может быть сколько угодно. Вот объект типа с данным именем может быть только один. Но это линкер видит. Если есть два объекта с одинаковым именем линкер ругается и сборка не проходит.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Тут проблема с шаблонными функциями и методами шаблонных классов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat С шаблонными функциями тоже нет проблем. Если шаблон функции инстанцирован два раза одинаковыми аргументами, то получается два объекта с одним именем. Линкер так же руганется.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 При неявном инстанцировании - не руганется, потому что шаблоны функций всегда считаются `inline`. Иначе глупо получалось бы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Для таких объектов линкер оставляет только один экземпляр. Ну да, линкер должен быть немного поумнее, чем старый сишный линкер. И формат объектника тоже посложнее, чем в чистом Си.

Comment: Это зависит от реализации. Обычно выделяют 3 алгоритма. Краткое описание смотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5095104/10743113). Длинное есть в книге C++ Templates, The Complete Guide

Comment: Собственно, чем это отличается от обычной inline функции? Из нескольких идентичных реализаций выбирается любая, механизм точно тот же.

Comment: Как я и предполагал ([тут чей-то длинный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44346057/7286264)) скомпилированные в разных единицах шаблонные функции помечаются атрибутом [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) (линкер включает в результат одну из них и не ругается на множественные определения)

Answer (score 3):

Для шаблонов нет никакой "проблемы с ODR".
ODR также работает и для шаблонов:

> **6.2 One-definition rule**
>   1. No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

т.е. **в одной единице трансляции не может быть нескольких определений шаблона**:

```
template<typename T> struct Some {};    
template<typename T> struct Some {};//Ошибка
```

Что касается определений в разных единицах трансляции (не только шаблоны), то они могут появляться, если удовлетворяют ряду требований.

> 12. There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 10),
>       enumeration type (9.6), inline function with external linkage (9.1.6),
>       inline variable with external linkage (9.1.6), class template (Clause
>       12), non-static function template (12.6.6), concept (12.6.8), static
>       data member of a class template (12.6.1.3), member function of a class
>       template (12.6.1.1), or template  specialization for which some
>       template parameters are not specified (12.8, 12.6.5) in a program
>       provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit,
>       and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>       such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> *список требований, который вряд ли имеет смысл приводить в данном ответе, т.к. предполагаем, что шаблон им всем удовлетворяет*
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit,
>   then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the
>   template’s enclosing scope used in the template definition (12.7.3),
>   and also to dependent names at the point of instantiation (12.7.2). If
>   the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the behavior
>   is as if there were a single definition of D. [Note: The entity is
>   still declared in multiple translation units, and 6.5 still applies to
>   these declarations. In particular, lambda-expressions (7.5.5)
>   appearing in the type of D may result in the different declarations
>   having distinct types. — end note] If the definitions of D do not
>   satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

т.е. **при множественном определении шаблона в разных единицах трансляции поведение такое же, как если бы определение было всего одно**.

Как конкретно это будет делать реализация стандарт не уточняет.
В C++ используется декорирование имен (name mangling, name decoration), поэтому при инстанцировании шаблона с заданным набором аргументов, имена полученных определений будут искажены. Одинаковые имена этих определений будут указывать на то, что это повторяющееся определение, полученное при инстанцировании шаблона, соответственно линковщик в праве оставить лишь одно из них, удалив всё лишнее.

Comment: imho автор вопроса хотел рассказа о **механизме реализации**