# На каком этапе компиляции обрабатываются шаблоны?

Tags: c++

Если директивы препроцессора обрабатывает препроцессор, то на каком этапе компиляции обрабатываются шаблоны?
Я отчего то думал, что этим то же занимается препроцессор, но посмотрев в его вывод, обнаружил, что шаблоны не были заменены.

Comment: Шаблон компилируется только если есть его инстанцирование

Comment: @bob torus  Я как раз из за этого и решил, что он обрабатывается на этапе препроцессинга.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В большинстве популярных реализаций никакого отдельного этапа для обработки шаблонов в последовательности фаз трансляции не требуется. Шаблоны обрабатываются на этапе... компиляции, т.е. когда компилируется все остальное.

Доминируют сейчас реализации (MSVC, GCC, Clang), которые независимо и безусловно транслируют все требуемые инстанцирования шаблонных сущностей в каждой единице трансляции, возможно порождая множественные копии одного и того же объектного кода (и данных), разбросанные по разным объектным файлам. Затем линкеру поручается задача по удалению дубликатов.

Однако существуют и такие "необычные" реализации, как, например, "родной" компилятор С++ в Sun Solaris: сначала компилятором собирается предварительная информация о требуемых инстанцированиях шаблонов, затем она обрабатывается глобально линкером, и только затем снова вызывается компилятор и один раз делается трансляция требуемых определений шаблонов.

Comment: @Nik: Я не вижу в процитированном вами ни слова о шаблонах.

Comment: Может подскажете, где почитать про этапы компиляции, подробно, на примере любой доминирующей реализации?

Comment: [Возможные реализации удаления дубликатов линкером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924079/317064)